# What the probability of rolling a number?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A die has been "loaded" so that the probability of rolling any even number is $\frac{3}{15}$ and the probability of rolling any odd number is $\frac{2}{15}$. (Assume the die is six sided with each side numbered one through six. Enter your probabilities as fractions.)

What is the probability of rolling a $2$, given that an even number is rolled?

I tried to solve it by assuming that:

- $A$ is the event of rolling an even number
- $B$ Is the event of rolling a $2$
  Then I used the conditional probability form:
  $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B )}{P(B)},$$
  where
  $P(A) = \frac{3}{15}$ is given, $P(B) = \frac13 \cdot\frac{3}{15}$.

I am not pretty sure of $P(B)$ and I do not know how to find $P(A \cap B )$.
Any help please?

Comment: The even numbers are all equally probable, so $\frac 13$.

Comment: try to sketch tree diagram it will help you

Comment: I think you mislabeled your events $A$ and $B$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: I am sorry Sir I posted my question from the mobile. I know how to format a math problem but I thought that on phone things would be different! Thanks for your help and support either way :)

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know how to find $P(A \cap B )$

That part doesn't have to be hard. If $A$ is the event of rolling an even number and $B$ is the event of rolling a 2, then $B$ is a subset of $A$. So $A\cap B=B$ and in particular, $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$.

That said, before plugging in those numbers, you should still double-check your computation of $P(B)$!

Comment: But Sir, according to your assumption the answer will be $= 1$ no matter what $P(B)$ will be ..

Comment: Yes, of course $P(A|B)$ will be $1$: the probability of rolling an even number given that you roll a $2$ is of course $1$! .... but you also do now want to know $P(A|B)$ ... you want to know $P(B|A)$!

Comment: Yes you are right I mislabeled the events . My mistake !!

Comment: Right idea (+1). My (b).

Answer (score 1):

(a) Intuitively (per @lulu's Comment): Even numbers are equally likely and `2` is one of three even numbers, so $1/3.$

(b) Formally, by conditional probability:
$$P(2 | E) = \frac{P(2 \cap E)}{P(E)} = \frac{P(2)}{P(E)}
= \frac{3/15}{9/15} = \frac 13.$$

(c) By simulation of ten million rolls of the unfair die in R: Also, $1/3.$ With ten million rolls one can expect about three place accuracy. (Brackets indicate conditioning; `|` means *or*.)

```
set.seed(1202)
prob = c(2,3,2,3,2,3)/15
roll = sample(1:6, 10^7, rep=T, p=prob)
table(roll)/10^7
roll
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.1334890 0.1999361 0.1335797 0.1997803 0.1332513 0.1999636 

mean(roll[roll==2 | roll==4 | roll==6] == 2)
[1] 0.3334046  # aprx 1/3
```